# Unable to cleanly close MFC application when in nested modal dialog (2 deep)

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog, exit

My application has a feature on the main window Help menu to check for update. It then optionally terminates the program to run the installer:

```
// If file was downloaded, we must close program
if (bQuit)
{
    // Begin install
    theApp.ExecuteProgram(strInstallEXE);
    // AJT 21.0.2 Suppress any automatic backup
    theApp.SetRestartAppMode(true);
    PostMessage(WM_CLOSE);
}
```

In itself there is no problem with that mechanism. But I hit an issue with some modifications I have been making. I added new controls to allow the user to perform the check automatically. These options are shown on a property sheet page. In themselves they are all work fine. But I then tried added a button to that property sheet page to check for for an update there and then. So the context is:

```
Main Dialog Window
    Options Window
        Additional Options Sheet
           Update Options Page
                Check button
```

In my button handler I was able to perform the check for update my simply posting the main menu handler:

```
AfxGetMainWnd()->PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, MENU_ID);
```

That this actually work. But since we are two modal dialogs deep when we performed this test the application would not close. At the moment I have removed this button from my GUI (since they can already check for updated on demand from the Help menu).

But is there a clean way for me to still close my application from the context described?

Comment: Have you tried `AfxGetMainWnd()->PostMessage(WM_CLOSE);`

Comment: @AdrianMole The thing is, the main menu handler is already doign that as you can see with it's own `PostMessage(WM_CLOSE)` so I think the issue is more to the fact that we have two modal dialogs on screen preventing it from working.

Comment: You have to find all the top level dialogs and close them one by one. But maybe the user is in the middle of typing input, you can't interrupt the user. It's better to redesign the upgrade procedure such that it gives up if it can't safely close the program. Then tell the user the upgrade will resume the next they restart the program.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani The context here is that the user has displayed the Options window and then displayed the More Settings window. Then they clicked the Update tab and decided to do a the check. There will not be any open windows or anything. But I agree it is messy to try to cater for. So I removed the button. After all, they can click Check for Update on the main app Help menu and in that context it can cleanly shutdown.